# How to scaffold a belongs_to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

Rails beginner here... literally working through intro tutorials, so apologies if this is a duplicate question.

I've created models for notes and categories, and scaffolding them both out. I can create notes and categories on their own. notes belong_to categories, and categories has_many notes.

How can I create a select so that on the new/edit note page I can choose from one of the already created categories for each note?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all change `belong_to` to `belongs_to` if you have like you wrote. Also you should have `category_id` field in `notes` table.

To select put `<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.title, c.id]} %>`

Answer (score 1):

check out http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html for different ways in which select can be used.